# Effective use of if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

i have three strings

```
String firstName; 
String lastName;
String companyName;
```

Here is my code and i am trying to see if i can modify and re write this in a better way

```
  if(firstName!=null && lastname == null) { comanyName = firstName;}
  if(lastname !=null && firstName== null) { comanyName = lastname ;}
  if(firstName!=null && lastname != null) { companyName = firstName.concat(lastName)}
```

Thanks

Comment: Might want to try [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) if your code is already working.

Comment: So, what happens if `firstName` and `lastName` are both `null`? @Dan Well, there are a lot of typos in his code, I doubt it even compiles.

Comment: from appearances, it looks like it'd fall through, and companyName would never get assigned...thus potentially causing issues later in the program, unless that's accounted for elsewhere.

Comment: If both first and last are non-empty, do you want a space between the names?

Answer (score 3):

Initialize all strings to an empty string:

```
String firstName = ""; 
String lastName = "";
String companyName = "";

companyName = firstName + lastName;
```

Now all your execution paths are covered. Is one of them is empty it will have the value of the other, if both are not-empty then it will be concatenated.

Comment: The only downside (and not covered in the OP's example) is that he/she may discover that they want a space between the names if they're both non-null.

Comment: @mbratch You can always add it and trim the string after, something like `companyName = (firstName +" "+ lastName).trim();`.

Comment: @ZouZou of course. But this answer didn't include that. ;)

Comment: @mbratch: I didn't include it because it wasn't covered in the question either. If he wants that space then it's a matter of trimming it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel understood. I think you have have a good answer. The OP just left that issue open. I asked that question of the OP in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would depend on what is the most common case. Re-write this to use an if-elseif construct, and include the most common case first, then next-most-common, etc. This way, when your code runs at least it will be at its most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using if else instead of if.  This way not everything goes through all of the if statements, since they are 3 distinct cases.

```
     if(firstName!=null && lastname == null) { comanyName = firstName;}
     else if(lastname !=null && firstName== null) { comanyName = lastname ;}
     else if(firstName!=null && lastname != null) { companyName = firstName.concat(lastName)}
```

This is a clearer, better approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (firstName != null) {
    if (lastName != null) {
        companyName = firstName.concat(lastName);
    }
    else {
        companyName = firstName;
    }
}

else {
    if (lastName != null) {
        companyName = lastName;
    }
    else {
        //What if they're both null?
    }
}
```